# Close the mobile menu by clicking or tapping outside

Tags: javascript, reactjs, menu, responsive

The code is for mobile menu but when I open it, it stays open and won't close.
I want it to close by clicking the menu links and tapping outside.
I know I haven't even added in the code but I don't know how to add into it.
Can anyone help me with the code? Any help is appreciated!

Here is the code :

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { HiMenuAlt3, HiX } from "react-icons/hi";

export default function NavBar() {
    const [navbar, setNavbar] = useState(false);

    return (
        <nav className="w-full bg-white shadow">
            <div className="justify-between px-4 mx-auto lg:max-w-7xl md:items-center md:flex md:px-8">
                <div>
                    <div className="flex items-center justify-between py-3 md:py-5 md:block">
                        <a href="javascript:void(0)">
                            <h2 className="text-2xl font-bold">LOGO</h2>
                        </a>
                        <div className="md:hidden">
                            <button
                                className="p-2 text-gray-700 rounded-md outline-none focus:border-gray-400 focus:border"
                                onClick={() => setNavbar(!navbar)}
                            >
                                {navbar ? (
                  <HiX className="text-4xl" />      // Close icon
                               ) : (
                  <HiMenuAlt3 className="text-4xl" />      // Open icon
                                )}
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div
                        className={`flex-1 justify-self-center pb-3 mt-8 md:block md:pb-0 md:mt-0 ${
                            navbar ? "block" : "hidden"
                        }`}
                    >
                        <ul className="items-center justify-center space-y-8 md:flex md:space-x-6 md:space-y-0">
                            <li className="text-gray-600 hover:text-blue-600">
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)">Home</a>
                            </li>
                            <li className="text-gray-600 hover:text-blue-600">
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)">Blog</a>
                            </li>
                            <li className="text-gray-600 hover:text-blue-600">
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)">About US</a>
                            </li>
                            <li className="text-gray-600 hover:text-blue-600">
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)">Contact US</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do have code to close it, `setNavbar(false)`. What you need is a hooked called `useOnClickOutside`. https://usehooks.com/useOnClickOutside/

To use it,

```
function NavBar() {
  const ref = useRef()
  useOnClickOutside(ref, () => setNavbar(false));

  return (
    <nav ref={ref}>
      ...
    </nav>
  )
}
```